# Alternative to repeatedly using dos2unix?

Tags: bash

I am learning bash scripting on windows using CYGWIN. I'm using dos2unix before executing my bash scripts but it gets rather tedious to keep running this tool after making any modifications to my scripts and before running them. Is there a way to run this tool automatically? or any work arounds?

Comment: Use an editor that does not use Windows line endings - there are many of these, some e.g. emacs are in cygwin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the completely free Notepad++ available for [download here](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Use an editor that supports unix newlines.

For example: [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows notepadto write the scripts then try downloading notepad++ and using this to write the scripts.

Alternatively use wordpad and save as a script rather than notepad.

Anyhow if you are using cygwin you should really attempt to use the CLI editors such as

vi

and some like

emacs

Answer (score 0):

Use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). It's extremely handy and useful open-source editor. You could easily convert one text file's format to another with one menu command. You could also your default new file format to UNIX format in the preferences.

You can also create a wrapper script like this to have a custom command for the editor when opening files (I use `write` and place it in `/usr/local/bin`).

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -e "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" ]]; then
    "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/notepad++.exe" "$@"
elif [[ -e "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" ]]; then
    "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" "$@"
else
    echo "notepadd++.exe can't be found."
fi
```

Or

```
#!/bin/bash
start "notepad++.exe" "$@"
```

Or as a cmd.exe script:

```
@start "Notepad++" /D"%CD%" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
```